# How to add different classes to my html code in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am working on WordPress theme, and using owl carousel, the problem is that I want to provide multiple carousel on same page and want to differentiate ids of those carousels so that it will not conflict .... how can I use any dynamic approach to avoid those conflicts ... because if I am using same classes or ids it conflicts and does not work ... here is my code ...

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'post_per_page' => 10,
    'post_status' => 'published'
);
$portfolio = new WP_Query($args);?>
<div class="portfolio-slider" id="portfolio-slider">
<?php if($portfolio->have_posts()){ while($portfolio->have_posts()){ $portfolio->the_post();
?>
    <div class="item">
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ the_post_thumbnail(); }?>
    </div>

<?php } } wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        $('#portfolio-slider').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            nav:true,
            items:3,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:2
                },
                600:{
                    items:3
                },
                1000:{
                    items:3
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

I want actually those `items` dynamic as user's select I will provide like that, but I don't know how to add any dynamic classes to my html id so that it can become like `#portfolio-slider` to `#portfolio-slider1` and `#portfolio-slider2` etc based on the usage of that same page etc

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking to call the sliders at different places it is better if you have all your code inside a function, you can call the function where ever you want and differentiate sliders by passing a unique parameter into the function.

I modified your code as below.

```
<?php

function getSlider($sliderNum) {
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'post_per_page' => 10,
    'post_status' => 'published'
);
$portfolio = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<div class="portfolio-slider" id="portfolio-slider<?php echo $sliderNum; ?>">
<?php if ($portfolio->have_posts()) {
    while ($portfolio->have_posts()) {
        $portfolio->the_post();
?>
            <div class="item">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
        } ?>
            </div>

    <?php }
} wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        $('#portfolio-slider<?php echo $sliderNum; ?>').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            nav:true,
            items:3,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:2
                },
                600:{
                    items:3
                },
                1000:{
                    items:3
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

You can call the function like  `getSlider('1')`,  `getSlider('2')`.

Comment: That's not the case bro, because if I have to do so I CAN do it as well, but I want any dynamic approach ... some thing like when ever user creates a slider a new id generated etc ... function calling is not good in mine case due to my scenario ...